# Proving that $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\geq c|h|$ for every $x\in K$ compact set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Let $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^1$ function defined over an open set $U\subset \mathbb R^m$. If $K\subset U$ is a compact set such that for every $x\in K$ the associated linear operator $f'(x): \mathbb R^m \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ is injective, then exists $c>0, \delta>0$ such that
>
> $$|f(x+h)-f(x)|\geq c|h|$$
>
> for every $x\in K$ and $|h|<\delta$.

**What I did so far:**

Since for every $x \in K$ the operator $f'(x)$ is injective, then it is a bijection between $\mathbb R^m$ and its image. Thus, there must exist a constant $c$ (very likely to be dependent on x) satisfying $|f'(x)h|\geq 2c|h|$. If I could, somehow, prove that this $c$ holds for every $x\in K$ or its bounded from above, I would be done; because in this case, since $f$ is $C^1$, it is uniformly differentiable and we obtain $\delta>0 $ such that $|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h| < c|h|$ for every $|h|<\delta$, $x\in K$. Therefore,

$|f(x+h)-f(x)|\geq |f'(x)h| - |f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h|\geq 2c|h| - c|h| = c|h|$

and it's over.

So the problem here is pretty much finding an argument to control, from above, the set of constants $c$ satisfying $|f'(x)h|\geq 2c|h|$. How can I do this? Should I use that $x\mapsto |f'(x)| $ attains a minimum value over $K$? I tried this one, but I wasn't successful.

Any help, hint?

Comment: Probably it is more useful to consider the map $(x,v)\mapsto |f'(x)h|$ on $D=K\times\mathbb{S}_{m-1}$. This maps in continuous on the compact set $D$ and so, it attained its minimum at some point $(x_0,v_0)\in K\times\mathbb{S}_{m-1}$. Since $f'(x)$ is injective for any $x\in K$, $c:=|f'(x_0)v_0|>0$. From this, it would follow that $|f'(x)h|=|h|\Big|f'(x)\tfrac{h}{|h|}\Big|\geq c|h|$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz It works. Would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we show that $|f'(x)h|>2x|h|$ for all $x\in K$ and $h\in\mathbb{R}^m$ under the conditions of the problem:

Define $\Psi:K\times\mathbb{S}_{m-1}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $\Psi(x,h)=|f'(x)h|$. Being a continuous function on a compact set, $\Psi$ attains its minimum value $c$ at some point $(x_0,v_0)\in K\times \mathbb{S}_{m-1}$. Since $f'(x)$ is injective for all $x\in K$ by assumption, $c=|f'(x_0)v_0)|>0$. Consequently

\begin{aligned}
|f'(x)h|&=|h|\Big|f'(x)\frac{h}{|h|}\Big|\geq |h|c,\qquad |h|>0\\
|f'(x)h|&=0=|h|c,\qquad h=0
\end{aligned}
a
for all $x\in K$.